# How does the stun fangs from a vampire works?

Tags: creature-design, electricity, vampires

I am looking for a biological mechanism to explain how a vampire's fangs could incapacitate a person using electricity much similar to the effect of a stun gun, they can also stun their own kind with their bites but no self electrocution from biting their own tongue. So they are not immune to electric shock and they can seemingly control the discharge of electricity at will through the fangs, no tech so no braces no parasites and please use magic sparingly. How do the stun fangs work?

Comment: Vampires get dry mouth just before biting. And they never keep their stun fangs connected they just release the safety when they intend to bite-to-stun (and that's also the signal on which their mouth dry instantly).

Comment: About the ' no self electrocution' rule: Does this only refer to death by shock, or do you mean to say: 'no self-shocking'? And, in both cases, is that a 99% rule (like, with an addled vampire biting herself in the arm would that still need to work?)

Comment: @bukwyrm: I do not want the vampire to accidentally shock themselves so maybe the fangs have some form of safety built-in to prevent electrical discharge when comes into physical contact with the tongue ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They produce an electric discharge in the same way the [electric eel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_eel) does.

> Electric eels have three pairs of abdominal organs that produce electricity: the main organ, Hunter's organ, and Sachs' organ. These organs make up four fifths of their body, and give electric eel's the ability to generate two types of electric organ discharges: low voltage and high voltage. These organs are made of electrocytes, lined up so a current of ions can flow through them and stacked so each one adds to a potential difference.
>
> When eels identify prey, their brain sends a signal through the nervous system to the electrocytes. This opens the ion channels, allowing sodium to flow through, reversing the polarity momentarily. By causing a sudden difference in electric potential, it generates an electric current in a manner similar to a battery, in which stacked plates each produce an electric potential difference. Electric eels are also capable of controlling their prey's nervous systems with their electrical abilities; by controlling their victim's nervous system and muscles via electrical pulses, they can keep prey from escaping or force it to move so they can locate its position

The fangs are used because, being air a better insulator than water, a conductive solution is needed, and what better solution than the inside of the target's body? The fangs act as application pins when stuck inside the body.

To reduce the chances of self-electrocution, the fangs act as one end of the circuit, while the hands act the other end.

Therefore when the vampire holds the target head or back with the hands while biting it's actually ensuring that the discharge flows between the hand and the fangs right through the brain or heart, granting the stun effect.

Comment: But they do still have to be careful not to bite their tongues. The electric eels actually do [zap themselves](https://www.forbes.com/sites/quora/2018/04/03/how-do-eels-generate-electricity-in-water-without-electrocuting-themselves/?sh=243a628764a0) by accident (or panicking while in a tight space)

Comment: Wouldn't a current moving through the brain or heart hurt or kill the victim though? Not sure that's what the OP wants.